# Can't change fill of d3.js rectangle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript

so I have this code -

```
bars.
  append('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', (d, i) ->
    return yScale(i)
  ).attr('width', (datum) ->
    return xScale(datum.freq)
  )
  .attr('height', barHeight)
  .attr('fill', 'blue')
  .attr('class', 'bar')
  .on('click', ->
    bars.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', '#0000ff')
    currentFill = d3.select(this).style('fill')
    nextColor = {}
    if currentFill == '#0000ff'
      nextColor = '#ff0000'
    else
      nextColor = '#0000ff'
    d3.select(this).style('fill', nextColor)
  )
```

However, the bars.selectAll('rect') is not changing the colour of the rectangles. Why?

Comment: The `bars.selectAll(...)` is changing the colour from blue to blue. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 5):

Replace `attr()` with `style()`. So your line:

```
bars.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', '#0000ff')
```

should be:

```
bars.selectAll('rect').style('fill', '#0000ff')
```

Comment: actually, it looks like the difference in the two in my fiddle above only exists when the CSS is also present: the style overrides it, the fill does not.  @praks, do you have CSS in your example?